# How to expand this equation to prove equality?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Prove

\begin{align}
\nabla_x[(Ax+b)^T (Ax+b)] = 2A^T(Ax+b)
\end{align}

With the assumption that $x$ is an $n$-dimensional vector, $A$ is an $n \times n$ dimensional symmetric matrix, and $b$ is a constant $n$-dimensional vector.

The right side looks like something that I could equate to if I expand. But when I do so it doesn't look like anything that helps. Which makes me assume I am doing something wrong.

\begin{align}
(Ax+b)^T (Ax+b) => (Ax^T)(Ax) + 2bAx + bb^T
\end{align}

Is there any way I can reduce this down more simply?

Comment: It is just the product rule for the inner product

Comment: To clarify max's comment, you might be more familiar with the term "dot product".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one writes it as sums then it might be easier
\begin{align}
f(x) &:= (Ax+b)^T (Ax+b) = (Ax+b)^2 = \sum_i (Ax+b)_i^2 
\\
&= \sum_i \left(\sum_j A_{ij} x_j + b_i\right)^2 \,.
\end{align}
Compute partial derivative using the chain rule
\begin{align}
\partial_{x_k} f(x) 
&= \sum_i 2 \left(\sum_j A_{ij} x_j + b_i\right) \partial_{x_k} \left(\sum_j A_{ij} x_j + b_i\right)  
\\
&= 2 \sum_i \left(\sum_j A_{ij} x_j + b_i\right) A_{ik}   
\\
&= 2 \sum_i A_{ik} (A x + b)_i     
\\
&= 2 \sum_i A_{ki}^T (A x + b)_i     
\\
&= 2 (A^T (A x + b))_k
\\
\implies \nabla f(x) &= 2 A^T (A x + b) \,.
\end{align}
For symmetric $A$ it can be further simplified
$$
\nabla f(x) = 2 A (A x + b) \,.
$$

Comment: Makes sense, I'm just confused as to how you go from this to that, (Ax+b)^T (Ax+b) = (Ax+b)^2

Comment: You might be confused because $Ax+b$ looks like a matrix? But it is nothing more than a vector $v:=Ax+b$ and for vectors it holds:
$$
v^T v = v^2 = \sum_i v_i^2 $$.